# "Listening Music"

Tags: prepositions, transitivity

I was just curious that is it okay to say/write "Listening Music" if we are not writing the whole sentence.

For example, if I have to write "Listening Music" under my Hobbies sections somewhere. Should I write "Listening to Music" or, "Listening music" will do?

Comment: Listening *to* music.  The preposition is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

- *Excuse me, but what's music listening to?*

As you can see this question would obviously raise in the heads of people who'd come across your phrase "**listening music**".

If you really convey this thought (that music is listening to something) then you can say it, otherwise you should say "**listening to music**" - *listening to what?*